# Object.Filter() error using boolean fields

Tags: django, pyodbc, django-mssql-backend

When I try to use `model.objects.filter(mybooleanfield=True)` gives me this error

```
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft] [SQL Server Native Client 11.0] [SQL Server] A non-Boolean expression was specified in a context where a condition was expected, near 'mybooleanfield'. (4145) (SQLExecDirectW) ")
```

But this only happens when use the filter with some `BooleanField` if I use `PositiveIntegerField, CharField, DateTimeField or TextField` there's no problem with the filter. I think this could be for the verions I use

```
Python 3.9.0
Django 3.1.3
Pyodbc 4.0.30
Django-mssql-backend 2.8.1
```

I need to use as condition my `BooleanField`. Someone knows why this happend?

Comment: Can you share an example of the line that is causing the issue ? Or a sample of your code. Give also the line where you define your BooleanField.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by Django 3.1.x.
More info here: https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/issues/69.

You can either downgrade django to 3.0.x or (which I recommend) use the latest master of https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend in which a patch has solved this issue for Django 3.1.x. There has been no release since this patch.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you recommend and works perfectly =)